# Does winforms app published using linux option run on the linux os?

Tags: linux, winforms, .net-5

I am using .net 5. I have built a windows forms app and when I publish it gives me an option to choose Linux.

Does that mean winforms app will run on Linux?

Comment: Attempts are there, https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues?q=is%3Aissue++linux+ but none succeeds yet.

Comment: So why does publish give that option?

Comment: It can be a waste of time to disable that option for WinForms apps. But if you want that change, ask Microsoft for a favor, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/feedback-options?view=vs-2019